# Why was this question re-migrated after Academia refused it?

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/posts/5207/revisions) was migrated to Academia, which [closed it](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/119809/36857) and rejected the migration.  Then, a moderator migrated it a second time.

- Why migrate it repeatedly?  Why not just close it after getting rejected?
- Did we override Academia's decision to reject?  Is it OK to re-migrate after a rejection?
- Academia [still records](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/119809/36857) the migration as rejected.  Is the software designed to support duplicate migrations?

Comment: Why do you believe it was migrated twice? I'm not saying you're wrong, but I can't find any evidence of that from my end.

Comment: I just looked further. A second migration is not in our mod histories, and it's not sitting twice on Academia, so I am not sure  what you're seeing.

Comment: Thesecretmaster solved it :) It was a miscommunication. I'm still curious about what you saw that led you to realize our mistake!

Comment: The post history says migrated two separate times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeated migrations were an accident/miscommunication on our mod team. We intended to only migrate it once. Originally, I checked with an academia moderator to see if we could migrate it there, and was told that it would be acceptable over there. The question then was closed on academia which rejected the migration. It seems that after the migration was rejected, Ben saw the question (which would've just had the "Closed as off-topic" banner) and assumed that we'd never migrated it in the first place and re-migrated it.

Once I talk to the rest of our moderators, I think we'll end up re-closing it as off topic. So, to answer your questions:

> Why migrate it repeatedly? Why not just close it after getting rejected?

It was a mistake/miscommunication. We did not intend to migrate it multiple times.

> Did we override Academia's decision to reject? Is it OK to re-migrate after a rejection?

It looks like re-migrating it just changed the banner over here and didn't change anything over there, so I don't think it's possible in the software re-migrate after rejection. So no, we did not override any rejection.

> Academia still records the migration as rejected. Is the software designed to support duplicate migrations?

It looks like it is, when a question is re-migrated it just replaces the banner on the question without un-rejecting the migration or anything like that.